# Change href link based on querystring parameter with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have some JavaScript:

```
var url = "http://www.google.com/" + value;
var element = document.getElementById('url');
element.setAttribute("href",url)
```

It changes the parameter on a href link based on the one currently in the querystring (rp=):

```
<a href="#" id="url">LOOK A LINK</a>
```

That works however it puts in the current URL and not one I specifiy i.e. http://www.google.com/, what needs to change in the code to do this?

Many thanks.

Comment: Your code looks correct, I suspect the issue beeing somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Please post more code, few lines above `var url = ...` will be helpful.

Comment: value is the parameter on the end of the base URL, in this case ?rp=887755, but the numbers need to change according to the URL. How do I define this?

Answer (score 0):

This error will be solved when you define "value"

```
var url = "http://www.google.com/" + value;
var element = document.getElementById('url');
element.setAttribute("href",url)
```

try removing this variable **OR** define it.

You can see the console for the error

Comment: If value was undefined, url would be `http://www.google.com/undefined` afterwards. Also, his problem is, that the attribute is set to "the current URL" and not the base url.

Comment: Yes, I also thought the same. But when I tried the same code where value is not defined, the link has the current url. And when I define variable "value" then the problem is solved.

Comment: @Prior No, if `value` was never declared it would throw. There's a difference between declaring a variable and defining it's value.

Comment: OKay, if it throws, then he is right, as the preset value of the <a> is "#"